# How to study static analysis?

Tags: static-analysis

I have read many papers and tutorials around on static analysis, but still I don't feel I have come closer to intermediate level in static analysis. I would like to begin step by step and get a deep knowldedge into the subject.

So... How should I go studying program/static analysis? What's the best way? Is there any best book for static analysis? From where can I start?

I would really like this question to manage to collect the few pearls among the dozens of material about static analysis that are published every year.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems more appropriate to cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: What is the reason of interest? I am also interested in this topic. My note: http://www.viva64.com/en/t/0046/ . Ready for discussion in e-mail: karpov [@] viva64.com.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. Or try at http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @FernandoCorreia +@Barmar I'm sorry as a newbie to stack overflow, I didn't know about cs.stackexchange. Should I move it there, then? Or any admin will do it?

Comment: @AndreyCpp I'm interested to follow a master degree specialized in this topic and I would like to prepare myself (and reassure me also that I really like this subject :P)

Comment: @emma No worries, I'm just letting you know about that resource. I'm not sure there will be an automatic migration. I suggest you read that site's FAQ and consider creating a question there. Make it more specific, though. As it stands, it's too broad.

Comment: @emma: I think SO treats lots of newbies badly in this way.  You probably have to move your question or SO policy fanboys will close it and it will effectively vanish.

Comment: @IraBaxter Thanks Ira. But ...how can I "move" it? Should I just repost it there? ¨/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the earlier discussion here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414328/static-analyzer/10416352).  Disclaimer:  There’s a link there to a [discussion](http://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&gid=1973349&type=member&item=3688456&qid=a2c1f14d-292b-4af1-8dad-49f473911be3&trk=group_featured_list-0-b-ttl&goback=%2Egmr_1973349%2Egfl_1973349) in the LinkedIn Static Analysis group I founded (registration required, and sorry I’m behind in approving membership requests), which mentions a couple of my [articles](http://www.drdobbs.com/testing/deploying-static-analysis/240003801).

Comment: Thanks a lot @FlashSheridan. I already follow your group. Taking a look at that discussion. Which one of this books that are mentioned would you suggest me? My main problem is not to find any material, but in which order should I read them in order to feel really that I'm "into" static-analysis and that I get a deeper understanding into it step by step. Thanks in advance!

Comment: My recommended order would be to start with Engler’s non-technical paper, “A few billion lines of code later: using static analysis to find bugs in the real world” (http://stanford.edu/~engler/BLOC-coverity.pdf).  I’m intrigued that Professor Engler’s web page now says that you can ask him for his original version.  I’d like to think that the second step would be my Dr Dobbs article (http://www.drdobbs.com/testing/deploying-static-analysis/240003801).  I’m afraid the right third step still doesn’t exist; in the meantime I’d suggest the Fortify book, _Secure Programming with Static Analysis_.

Comment: @emma: I second Flash's recommendation of Engler's paper.  That guy is *really* *really* smart, and his writeup gives a lot of insight into the problems of applying static analysis in the real world.  Flash having the very good taste to suggest Engler, hints  his other suggestions are pretty good, too.

Comment: Following the discussion that Flash mentioned in his answer, Ive already read these two articles-papers...so I will soon start with the Fortify book. Thanks both of you

Answer (score 1):

You can read lots of papers, but some real experience will help you understand the issues more effectively.

I suggest you get a "static analysis tool" (anything that claims it is one) and run it on real code.  Then ask yourself:

- what (static analysis) questions does this answer?
- how accurate are the answers?
- how *useful* are the answers?

Having some experience with this will help guide your reading choices considerably to your benefit.

At some point, it is good to try to *build* a static analysis tool, to get a personal understanding ofthe effort it takes, and what goes wrong.  You'll learn a lot about the limits of your specific static analysis approach, and why there are so many.

Comment: Thanks Ira. I am already quite familiar with Soot framework. I did a visualization tool for eclipse plugin as part of my thesis. But I still don΄t feel that ready to answer questions like the ones that you listed. That΄s why, I΄d like to get a deeper understanding into the subject

Comment: I have already in my near plans the build of a static analysis tool, but until that time Id like to have a better background. Any suggestions-proposals are very welcomed indeed.